# iPython notebook not uploading my .txt file

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I converted some excel files to .txt files (Text (tab delimited)), carefully saved them in the same folder as my notebook, made sure there were no copies anywhere on my computer, checked the .txt files could all be opened in Notebook, and after using the command '%pylab inline' to load all the functions I usually use, triple checked that mt .txt files were in the same folder as the notebook by using the 'ls' command. I then used loadtxt('filename.txt') to load my data and it gave me errno 2: no such file or directory: 'filename.txt'. I triple checked that I had spelled everything correctly and I can't understand why it's not working. I need these data analysing today for a lab report due in tomorrow - help! Here's my code:

```
%pylab inline
ls
loadtxt('Physical_lab_experiment_2_25_degrees_with_times.txt')
```

and here is the error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c8d929572f25> in <module>()
----> 1 loadtxt('Physical_lab_experiment_2_25_degrees_with_times.txt')

C:\Users\Daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in     loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols,  unpack, ndmin)
738                 fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))
739             else:
--> 740                 fh = iter(open(fname))
741         else:
742             fh = iter(fname)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:   'Physical_lab_experiment_2_25_degrees_with_times.txt'
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the absolute path to the file?

Comment: Ah not yet, will give it a go and let you know if it works!

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately :(

Comment: I have now also tried uninstalling and re-installing python, this didn't work either.

Comment: try `import os; print(os.getcwd()); print(os.listdir('.'))` to see what the current directory is and what is there...

Comment: I tried it, the command you gave me confirms what the 'ls' command told me - the files I want tot upload are definitely there and available!

Comment: Can you open it (`open("Physical_lab_experiment_2_25_degrees_with_times.txt")`)?

Answer (score 0):

loadtxt is a numpy function. Import numpy like:

```
import numpy as np
data= np.loadtxt('Physical_lab_experiment_2_25_degrees_with_times.txt')
print data
```